# Android Studio - Error al intentar mostrar valor en el Toast

Tags: android-studio, string, cast

estoy queriendo mostrar un valor int que lo casteo desde un string en un Toast pero me dá un error que no entiendo.

Cuando realizo esos pasos, me tira el siguiente error el Logcat:

> ```
> Process: com.example.rodrigo.libros, PID: 18227
> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
> ```

Esta es la parte del código donde estoy realizando lo que les digo:

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    BaseDeDatos admin = new BaseDeDatos(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = admin.getWritableDatabase();
    Libros catego = null;
    int cat;

    listaLibros = new ArrayList<>();
    cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from libros" , null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        catego = new Libros();
        catego.setId(cursor.getString(0));
        listaLibros.add(catego);
        cat = Integer.parseInt(catego.getId());

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Es decir, catego.getId() me trae el valor "1" (String), entonces uso la variable cat para castear este valor a int (1), pero cuando quiero mostrar su valor en el Toast para comprobar que todo va bien, me da ese error antes mencionado.

Si se preguntan para que lo quiero castear a int, es porque luego le quiero sumar un valor a cat, (por ejemplo: cat + 3)

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se debe a que, el `Toast` recibe como valor un `String` y tu le estás mandando un `integer`. Lo que puedes hacer es convertir el `integer` en el `Toast` a `String` de la siguiente manera:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(cat), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Aunque si quieres evitar la conversión, simplemente pasa el `cursor.getString(0)` o el `catego.getId()` directamente en el `Toast` de la siguiente manera:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cursor.getString(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**o**

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), catego.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: claro, para mostrarlo tengo que volver a convertirlo a String, yo pense que lo podia mostrar directamente como un int. Muchas gracias!

Comment: También podrías pasarlo directo si lo concatenas con comillas así:

cat + ""